# Login MVVM / Labels

Tags: xamarin

i have a question regarding to Binding. I have a Login that I now decided to transfer to MVVM until now i had labels with content "wrong password" and such in code behind and i was setting their visibility. Btw I do have RESX file and I am binding my labels, just not sure how to approach this.

```
bool isPreparedToBeSubmitted = true;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
            {
                isPreparedToBeSubmitted = false;
                emailValLabel.IsVisible = true;

            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
            {
                isPreparedToBeSubmitted = false;
                 passwordEntryValLabel.IsVisible = true;
            }
```

But I think this can be done much nicer, but I am not sure how. Do i get the visibility bool in Model and then set binding to the label in View?

Comment: Does my answer work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use MVVM. It would be better to bind the text of entry to ViewModel . Don't forget to set the binding mode as **OneWayToSource** .

You could check the following demo . The page contains two entries . The submit button will appear when user both input the user name and password .

#### in xaml

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

    <Entry Placeholder="input username"  Text="{Binding UserName,Mode=OneWayToSource}" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="200" />
    <Entry Placeholder="input password"  Text="{Binding Password,Mode=OneWayToSource}" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="200" />

    <Button Text="Submit" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"  Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"  />

</StackLayout>
```

#### in ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ICommand SubmitCommand { get; set; }


    //IsVisible

    bool isVisible;
    public bool IsVisible
    {

        get
        {
            return isVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isVisible != value)
            {
                isVisible = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        }

    }
    string userName;
    public string UserName
    {

        get
        {
            return userName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (userName != value)
            {
                userName = value;
                IsSubmitVisible();
                NotifyPropertyChanged("UserName");
            }
        }

    }



    string password;
    public string Password
    {

        get
        {
            return password;
        }
        set
        {
            if (password != value)
            {
                password = value;
                IsSubmitVisible();
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Password");
            }
        }

    }

    void IsSubmitVisible()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
        {
            IsVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsVisible = false;
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        SubmitCommand = new Command(()=> {


            //...

        });
    }

}
```